# HTML file as a variable in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, sendgrid

I need to send something as a html via email (I'm using Sendgrid) with simple Node.js server. I'm just sending some text with variables in them and line breaks.

```
var postData = 'lat: ' + formatted.latitude + '<br>lng: ' + formatted.longitude + '<br>time: ' + formattedDate;
sendEmail(postData);
```

Then I'm sending the email with Sendgrid as a HTML.

```
var content = new helper.Content('text/html', messageContent);
```

No need to paste remaining blocks of code.

What I need is more complex .html file with css and javascript in it. Moreover I need to change some values in it. What is the easiest way to assign this file to variable and send it like this?

Comment: So you need a template with variable placeholders in it in order to construct HTML markup (technically a string or a stream) from this template and data. I think [PUG](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) would help.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin ok, I will give it a try

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not shure if i understood the question, but you can read the file really simple. Just

```
var fs = require('fs'); //Filesystem    

var content = fs.readFileSync("path/to/File/file.html","utf-8");
//this is the content of your file.html
```

if you keep it simple, you could just use a type of regular expression and replace something with the value.. If it has to be more complex, i would recommend you using a template engine. My personal preference is [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).
There is also a libary for nodejs of mustache, called [Mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache).
In this case you use it like this:

```
const mustache   = require('mustache');
const fs = require('fs'); //Filesystem    
//...
var content = fs.readFileSync("path/to/File/file.html","utf-8");
var view = {formatted:{latitude: 0,longitude:0}, formattedDate:"01/01/1990"}
var output = mustache.render(content, view);
```

For doing this, you have to understand mustache first, but it is really simple. See a tutorial [here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

Your **file.html** then should look like this:

```
<div> lat: {{formatted.latitude}} <br> lng: {{formatted.longitude}} </div>
<script>
     var formattedDate = "{{formattedDate}}";
</script>
```

**Note you have to install mustache with** `npm install mustache` **first**

Comment: What about manipulating the javascript inside the .html? I need to append values inside the array.

Comment: think you can do it like <script> var array = {{mustache_array}}; </script>

Comment: There was a mistake, it should be: `var content = fs.readFileSync("./mustache.html").toString();` because we have to pass the template as a string. Thanks!

Comment: To have it more correct, you should use fs.readFileSync("path/file","utf-8/ or other encoding"); then you get a string, not a stream. My fault